# the ltbb flag in g++-10 compiler

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, g++, tbb

I have installed tbb library with:
`brew install tbb`.
But when I'm trying to compile a program with:

```
g++-10 hello.cpp -o hello --std=c++2a -Wall -ltbb -lpthread -O3
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ld: library not found for -ltbb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All the other flags work fine.

If I use `-tbb` instead of `ltbb`, I get

```
g++-10: error: unrecognized command-line option '-tbb'
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the linker cannot find `libtbb.dylib` on your Mac.  It cannot find it because Homebrew installs the TBB libraries in a non-standard folder (one that is, by default, not inside your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, which is what `ld` uses to search for `.dylib`s).

I ran into this same issue and found that `libtbb.dylib` (along with symlinks to all the other libraries installed with `brew`) are in `/opt/homebrew/lib`.  So, you could do something like `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}` before running your `g++` command, or if you are using a build system like CMake, you can add a command like `link_directories("/opt/homebrew/lib")` inside your `CMakeLists.txt`).